# How to include guild name in welcome message using discord.py

Tags: python-3.x, discord.py

I'm very new to using discord.py and python in general so please bear with me.

My current goal is to make my discord bot send a welcome and a leave message to a certain channel when a person joins or leaves. In that message I would like to include both the person's name and the name of the server, guild, being joined, or left.

The code I have so far is:

```
@client.event
async def on_member_join(member):
print(f'Greetings {member}, welcome to server')
```

I know that this only prints the message in the terminal.  I don't know how to make the bot send a message to a text channel. I do know that you can use .send, however, I don't know which object to use before it, channel, ctx, etc.

I also have confusion in regards to collecting the server name.  I've tried using discord.Guild.name but that only returns <member 'name' of 'Guild' objects>.

I have tried looking through the documentation to fix my problem but either I'm blind and can't find the solution or too dumb to realize the solution when I see it.

Please point me in the right direction to solving my issue or provide the correct code I should use, anything constructive and helpful is greatly appreciated and desired.

Thanks for reading this post and potentially aiding me.

Best regards, Kelsier

EDIT:

The main issue that I have been running into is the fact that you need a message parameter and then have a message be sent in chat to then have the bot react and send a message. This is troublesome because in the on_member_join and on_member_remove events the only parameter is member, removing the possibility, at least I think so, to define and then send a message.

From reading the documents there doesn't seem to be an easy print-statement like function that simply sends a message, which is very annoying.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
@client.event
async def on_member_join(member):
channel = client.get_channel(ID) # Where ID is your welcome channel's ID

# Send welcome message to channel
await channel.send(f'Welcome {member}!, Enjoy your stay at {member.guild.name}!')
```

[Client.get_channel](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.Client.get_channel)

Comment: No problem! :).

Answer (score 0):

you can get the guild name via the member

```
@client.event
async def on_member_join(member):
print(f'Greetings {member}, welcome to {member.guild.name}')
```

Comment: Thank you so much, that works perfectly. 

Do you also happen to know how to send this message to a text channel within the server instead of just printing it in the terminal?

Answer (score 0):

```
@client.event
async def on_member_join(member):
print(f'Greetings {member.mention}, welcome to {member.guild.name}')
```

This is the welcome message, it says Greetings @Username, welcome to server name

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Code-only answers are not particularly helpful. Please add some descriptions of how this code solves the problem.

Comment: Code-only answers are not particularly helpful. Please add some descriptions of how this code solves the problem.